# Convert to normal numerical array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array whose elements are like this `{{{c2 -> 2917.68}}, {{c2 -> 1921.78}}, ... ]`. I am unable to `ListPlot` this array. It givess `ListPlot called with 0 arguments` error. 
How can I convert this to normal array?

Comment: One possibility :`ListPlot[{{{c2 -> 2917.68}}, {{c2 -> 1921.78}}}[[All,1,1,2]]]`

Comment: @andre That works. But can I use the same if my array size is large?

Comment: Yes, there's no limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot @ Flatten @ Values @ {{{c2 -> 2917.68}}, {{c2 -> 1921.78}}}
```

[image]