# How to remove arrows and brackets from this list with

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some lists which have many brackets. I'd like to remove arrows from the lists.

For example, I need to change the list

```
{{x->a},{x->b},{x->c},{x->d}}
```

into

```
{a,b,c,d}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139656/5478

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669) as well.

Comment: `x/.{{x->a},{x->b},{x->c},{x->d}}`,and I will vote to close as simple question.

Comment: `lst[[All, 1, 2]]`

Comment: Read here: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/12

Comment: `Flatten@Values@{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c}, {x -> d}}`